# EditText values not going to onclick section

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am still very new to android. 
I have done a lot of html, php, visual basic, and some C languages coding but Java/Android is still a raw run for me.

When I run the code below and try to verify syntax of the box_email EditText field I get a null value and it crashes the emulator. If I pass it a default string like lll@aol.com it works and also works if I pass it lll@blah. It correctly identifies the valid and invalid syntax but cannot see any data being passed from the form.

```
    package test.com;

    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Spinner;


    public class testActivity extends Activity {
        int MediaState;
        ImageView animation;
        String EMAILTEXT;
        EditText box_email, box_password, box_username;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Eula.show(this);
    IntroMedia(0);
            animation = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageAnimation);
            animation.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fpanim);     // the frame-by-frame animation defined as a xml file within the drawable folder
            Button d;
            (d = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next1button)).setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.next));
        }

        public void myClickHandler1(View view) {
            setContentView(R.layout.credentials);
            IntroMedia(1);
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.box_state);    
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.states_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);    
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);    
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            EditText box_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.box_email);

            //Button mainNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextScreenMain); 
    //Filter Username
            EditText box_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.box_username); 

            box_username.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    String filtered_str = s.toString();

                        if (filtered_str.matches(".*[^a-z^0-9^A-Z].*")) {

                        filtered_str = filtered_str.replaceAll("[^a-z^0-9^A-Z]", "");

                        s.clear();
                        s.append(filtered_str);



                    }

                }

                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
                });
    //End Filter Username
    //Filter Password
            EditText box_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.box_password); 
            box_password.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    String filtered_str = s.toString();

                        if (filtered_str.matches(".*[^a-z^0-9^A-Z].*")) {

                        filtered_str = filtered_str.replaceAll("[^a-z^0-9^A-Z]", "");

                        s.clear();
                        s.append(filtered_str);


                    }

                }

                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
                });
    //End Filter Password
    //Filter Email


            box_email.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    String filtered_str = s.toString();

                        if (filtered_str.matches(".*[^a-z^0-9^A-Z.@_/-].*")) {

                        filtered_str = filtered_str.replaceAll("[^a-z^0-9^A-Z.@_/-]", "");

                        s.clear();
                        s.append(filtered_str);

                    }

                }

                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
                });
    //End Filter Email 
            Button cred_submit;
            cred_submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cred_submit);
            cred_submit.setOnClickListener(myClickHandler_Cred_Submit);    


        }

        private OnClickListener myClickHandler_Cred_Submit = new OnClickListener()   
        {   

            public void onClick(View v)   
            {          
                IntroMedia(1); 
                EMAILTEXT = box_email.getText().toString();   

                //Validate Email Pattern
                if (checkEmail(EMAILTEXT)){
                    //is valid
                    setContentView(R.layout.validinput);
                } else {
                    //is not
                    setContentView(R.layout.invalidinput);
                }
                //End Validate EMail Pattern

                //process & validate data
                //submit data to website
                //enter data into prefs   

            }   

        };   



        public void myClickHandler_Cred_Cancel(View view) {
        finish();   
        }
        @Override
        /**
         * This method is called whenever the Activity becomes visible or invisible to the user.
         * During this method call its possible to start the animation.
         */
        public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
            AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = 
                (AnimationDrawable) animation.getBackground();
            if(hasFocus) {
                frameAnimation.start();
            } else {
                frameAnimation.stop();
            }
        }

        public void IntroMedia(int MediaState) {

             MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.smallmusicfile);
            if (MediaState == 1){
                mPlayer.pause();
                mPlayer.seekTo(mPlayer.getDuration()); 
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.release();
             }
             if (MediaState == 0){
                    mPlayer.start();
                   MediaState = 1;
                 } 

            }

        public final Pattern EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" + "\\@" + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" + "(" + "\\." + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" + ")+"); 

        private boolean checkEmail(String email) {return EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN.matcher(email).matches(); } 
    }
```

This is my main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"


    >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageAnimation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"

    />
    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">   
      <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                             ads:adSize="BANNER"
                             ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
      <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="myClickHandler1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/next1button" android:layout_above="@+id/adView" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></Button>

    </RelativeLayout> 
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my credentials.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"


    >

    <TextView android:text="Username: REQUIRED - Unique and Alpha Numeric " android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/label_username" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/box_username" android:layout_below="@+id/label_username" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></EditText>
    <TextView android:text=" " android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/blank_1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_below="@+id/box_username" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>
    <TextView android:text="Password: REQUIRED - Alpha Numeric" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/label_password" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_below="@+id/blank_1" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/box_password" android:layout_below="@+id/label_password" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:inputType="textPassword"></EditText>
    <TextView android:text=" " android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/blank_2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_below="@+id/box_password" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>
    <TextView android:text="Email: Optional" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/label_email" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_below="@+id/blank_2" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>
    <EditText 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/box_email" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/label_email" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress">
    </EditText>
    <TextView android:text=" " android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/blank_3" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_below="@+id/box_email" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>
    <TextView android:text="State: Optional - If in the U.S. only." android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/label_state" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_below="@+id/blank_3" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>
    <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/box_state" android:layout_below="@+id/label_state" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:prompt="@string/state_prompt" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></Spinner>
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Submit" android:id="@+id/cred_submit" android:layout_below="@+id/box_state" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:onClick="myClickHandler_Cred_Submit"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Cancel" android:id="@+id/cred_cancel" android:layout_below="@+id/box_state" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:onClick="myClickHandler_Cred_Cancel"></Button>




    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">   
      <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                             ads:adSize="BANNER"
                             ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


    </RelativeLayout> 




    </RelativeLayout>
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: What is equals null? Or can you show stack trace of NullException? And why do you copy your code of TextWatcher to all of your variables? You should create one instance of some class that extends TextWatcher and pass it to all of your EditText's. And please use java code conventions, because otherwise your code is hard to read and understand.

Comment: EMAILTEXT = box_email.getText().toString();

is coming up NULL

Comment: just to be clear, is EMAILTEXT null, or box_email, or box_email.getText()?

Comment: when I declare that EMAILTEXT to equal box_email box_email is null so therefore so is EMAILTEXT.

Answer (score 3):

Your box_email is null because you initialize local variable box_email

```
EditText box_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.box_email);
```

, not the class field. So just replace specified line to:

```
box_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.box_email);
```

And it will have to work.

And several advices.

1. Don't forget about java code conventions.
2. You should not invoke `setContentView` with different layouts in different places within your activity without sufficient reasons, because it will headache for you to be sure that view fields are in actual state, and not null. Use several activities instead of it. One activity - one layout.